# If React Native runs with 60fps maximum, how can events be processed faster

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I have done some intense performance evaluation of the communication between native code and the JS runtime of react native. Now i see that events are received quite fast.

On an iphone se its about `1.01ms` that an event needs to be send via `[self sendEventWithName: body:]`. (I am sending`an sent-timestamp`[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]and comparing it to the received timestamp `Date.now()`

How can this be if the js runtime runs on 60fps max, which is 16.67ms per cycle? I would expect the deltas to be equally spread in the range of [0 .. 16.67].

Any ideas?

Comment: Framerate has nothing to do with code execution. The JS runtime is not coupled to the framerate in any way

Comment: okay. so reading this article https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html i assume that the JS thread is running as fast as it can. and the ui/main thread is locked to 60fps?

Comment: but what is the perf monitor showing then. UI = 60 okay, but JS = 60?

Comment: The JS runtime will run as fast as it can to create frames, the OS will have an idea of what the next frame will be so when the screen redrawing needs to happen it will draw what the app told it to draw. That doesn't mean that the app needs to keep in sync with the OS or screen refresh rate. It only means that even if you do calculate a state more frequently than every 16ms the screen will only reflect a change every 16ms. It also means if your recalculation takes longer than 16ms even by 1 ms you will lose the "bus" to the next screen redraw and will need to wait until the next cycle.

Comment: Why would you need more than 60fps anyway? I think only the iPad pro supports 120fps which is incredibly smooth.

Comment: i dont need more thatn 60fps. i misunderstood the doc and was just wondering.